# TimeMachine restore: Can select backup, but get "No macOS system backups were found"

Tags: macos, restore, time-machine

The SSD on my 2015 MacBook Pro died, and I got it replaced with a used SSD from another MacBook containing Catalina. The machine boots now normally, ready to restore from backup.

I tried to restore from Time Machine backup in the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> mode. I can connect to the Synology NAS where I have the TimeMachine backups, and see the backups of our family. When I select my "Peter's MacBook Pro" backup as the source, it churns for about 2 min with a "Looking for macOS system backups..." message, then shows a "No macOS system backups were found" message. So I can't proceed with the restore.

Logging in to the NAS I can see that the backup is there:

- directory `Peter's MacBook Pro.sparsebundle`
- sub-directories `bands` and `mapped`, the latest files in there match the day when the SSD failed, e.g. it's the most recent backup)
- files `info.bckup`, `info.plist`, `lock`, `token`, 4 files starting with `com.apple.*`

Googling I found that the extension changed from `.sparsebundle` to `.backupbundle` in Catalina, so I renamed the directory, and tried to restore again. No luck, same error, so I reverted the name change.

I suspect the reason why the backup does not work is that the OS is different. I *think* I had High Sierra, but I am not sure. I looked at the files in the backup, but none of the content of the XML files indicate the OS version.

I also tried to downgrade the OS from Catalina to High Sierra, but got an error message.

I am currently making a copy of the backup to an external 2 TB hard disk (the backup is 1.25 TB), which should finish in 7 hours.

I am at a loss this time. Any idea how to get the backup recognized?

**UPDATE 2023-03-21**

I tried the Migration Assistant approach, I can connect to the NAS, and see the list of backups of all family members. My backup is stuck in "Loading backup...". I left it for the whole day, after 8h it reverted back to the screen where you select the server to restore from.

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE 2023-04-27**

After many trials and errors I got the restore finally working:

- rename the extension from `.sparsebundle` to `.backupbundle`
- connect Time Machine to the NAS => it'll state no backups
- do a backup => latest backup shown as of today
- reduce the quota of the Time Machine user to have 500G free space left
- do another Time Machine backup => this forces Time Machine to clean up the backup and get rid of older snapshots
- enter Time Machine => older backups are now shown!
- restore

Moral of the story: Do not rely on Time Machine, it's too buggy! I am installing an rsyc cron to sync all files below my home directory to the NAS. I still use Time Machine, which is useful to restore single files.

I am posting this here in case anyone has the same issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is better suited for the [Apple specific SE site](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You do need the same OS version which was used to make the TimeMachine backups. If that's not an option or otherwise not working, you could try the [Migration Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203981). That should work on Catalina.

Comment: Thank you @Peregrino69, I'll try that.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: Why close? There are currently 21,706 questions tagged with `macos` on superuser

Comment: There is no reason at all to close just because it happens to be valid on two different stacks. However as it's now been posted to *both* stacks, that becomes valid reason to close this one. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Comment: @PeterThoeny I am voting to close and to migrate the question. The Apple specific SE would be more helpful in a question like this if you ask me.

Comment: I am in a time crunch and need to have a solution before I go on a trip abroad. So far only Giacomo provided a useful answer **here**, non on Ask Different. If one needs to be closed I vote the other one.

Comment: No luck with Migration Assistant either, see UPDATE in post. I did not expect TimeMachine to be that flaky. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and errors I got the restore finally working:

- rename the extension from `.sparsebundle` to `.backupbundle`
- connect Time Machine to the NAS => it'll state no backups
- do a backup => latest backup shown as of today
- reduce the quota of the Time Machine user to have 500G free space left
- do another Time Machine backup => this forces Time Machine to clean up the backup and get rid of older snapshots
- enter Time Machine => older backups are now shown!
- restore

Moral of the story: Do not rely on Time Machine, it's **too buggy**! I am installing an rsyc cron to sync all files below my home directory to the NAS. I still use Time Machine, which is useful to restore single files.

I am posting this here in case anyone has the same issue.